# Using the trim keyword in scala

Tags: scala, trim

I have a part of code in scala which is throwing error right now. Error message says reassignment to val. Below is the code snippet:

```
private def tokenize(line: String) {
    val words = line.split("\\s+")
    for (word <- words) {
      if (word == null) //continue
      word = word.trim()
      if (word.length == 0) //continue
      if (word == "WRITEINT") {
        addLast(new Token(TokenType.WRITEINT, word))
```

and this error apprears on line `word = word.trim()` How do I get rid of this error?

Comment: `val`s in Scala are immutable. You can only assign something to them once. If you want mutable state, you can use a `var`. However, it's often a good idea to avoid mutable state anyway so you might want to rethink your code.

Comment: So many of those `if`s are unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Because `word` is a `val` and therefore cannot be reassigned to an other value.

You can name it differently:

```
val trimmed = word.trim()
if (trimmed.length == 0)
// ...
```